# How to create thead and tbody in ASP.NET Table ?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-table

How to create thead and tbody in ASP.NET Table? I need those tags because of jquery and asp.net gives me only tr, th and td.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

<strike>[asp:Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx) does not support these elements.</strike>

> **Update:** As [jameh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552679/464709) reveals, the sentence above is completely wrong: the `TableSection` property allows to control
>   whether a given row goes into the table's header, body or footer.

To elaborate on his answer, it seems you can even achieve this declaratively by setting the `TableSection` property in your markup, without code behind:

```
<asp:Table id="yourId" runat="server">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow TableSection="TableHeader">
        <!-- ... -->
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <!-- 'TableSection' defaults to 'TableRowSection.TableBody'. -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow TableSection="TableFooter">
        <!-- ... -->
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

---

> *Original, now moot answer follows:*

You might want to try the [HtmlTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class instead:

```
<table id="yourId" runat="server">
    <thead>
        .
        .
        .
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        .
        .
        .
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What good is then this Asp:Table ? 
Can I create HtmlTable programaticly with C# code ?

Comment: Yes, [you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwhe0at8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), even if the syntax is probably less clear.

Comment: `asp:Table` is consistent with other web server controls. It'normally easier to develop with than `HtmlTable`. See http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4410/in-depth-aspnet-using-adonet/3/.

Comment: Read jameh's answer. This is possible to do with asp:Table

Comment: @InvisibleBacon, done, and answer corrected accordingly. Thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 21):

Frédéric's answer is not accurate. asp:Table DOES in fact support `<tbody>` and `<thead>` tags, but in a less obvious fashion than HtmlTable.

[UseAccessibleHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.useaccessibleheader.aspx) is true by default for tables, which means your header rows will be rendered properly with `<th>` instead of `<td>`, but to get the `<tbody>` and `<thead>` tags, you've just got to set some voodoo at Page_Load and when you're creating/inserting your rows in the codebehind.

Here's my example asp:Table markup:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblGeneral">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell1" runat="server">Column 1</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell2" runat="server">Column 2</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell3" runat="server">Column 3</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell4" runat="server">Column 4</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell5" runat="server">Column 5</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

At Page_Load, we specify that our TableHeaderRow1 should be a TableHeader:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TableHeaderRow1.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader      
End Sub
```

And finally, in your function that inserts rows into said table, you just have to specify that the TableRowSection of each row you add is a TableBody:

```
Dim row As TableRow
Dim dvRow As Data.DataRowView

For Each dvRow In dv
    row = New TableRow
    row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody 'THIS is the important bit
    cell = New TableCell
    Col1Stuff = New Label
    Col1Stuff.Text = "Blah"
    cell.Controls.Add(Col1Stuff)
    row.Cells.Add(cell)

    ...

tblGeneral.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

You can do more reading on the [TableRowSection property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.tablesection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx); looks like you can also accomplish this with your asp:Table template.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected. As I could not delete my answer in favour of yours (accepted answers cannot be deleted), I fixed it with the information you provided. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: No problem, always happy to share insight into the cryptic ASP.NET world. ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to create multiple tbodies dynamically?