# Server side HTML table with tbody not compiling in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create thead and tbody in ASP.NET Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015839/how-to-create-thead-and-tbody-in-asp-net-table)

The following HTML does not compile in an ASP.NET Website

```
<table runat="server" id="tbl1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I get this compilation error:

```
The best overloaded method match for ‘System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)’ has some invalid arguments
```

- This error started appearing after I installed VS2012 and .NET 4.5
- It occurs in both VS2012 and VS2010
- It appears in ASP.NET Website project template, the code compiles fine in ASP.NET WebApplication project template
- The error disappears when removing the "runat" attribute OR the "tbody" tag
- The weird thing is that the project fails to compile but publishes successfully without errors
- The page renders correctly in the browser
- If I uninstall VS2012 and .NET 4.5 the same code works again in VS2010

**Update:**

I'm not sure why this question was closed in the first place, it wasn't a duplicate. Anyway, Microsoft has acknowledged this as a bug and is working on a fix. More info [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766115/value-of-type-system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmlgenericcontrol-cannot-be-converted-to-system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmltablerow)

Comment: may be the tbody tag is not supported in asp:table, because when we add runat attribute inside the table it makes it to run on the server and act as asp:table

Comment: @DennisTraub I don't think it's a duplicate. It's related certainly, but this approaches the issue from the angle of an exception. Though the answer is in that question.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is considered a duplicate, I am not asking about how to create a table with tbody, but my question is about some strange behavior that started to occur after I installed VS2012 and .NET 4.5. The example in the question is just stripped down for simplicity.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. This is a build failure that occurs the other talks about how to add the table elements to an ASP.Net Table which is not even used in this question.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500332/html-table-tag-with-col-colgroup-tbody-and-thead-throws-compile-error-in-visu

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try :

```
  <table id="yourId" runat="server">
     <thead>
         .
         .
         .
     </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>
             </td>
          </tr>    
            </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I tried you example but the same error still appears