# Create multiple tbodies dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, html-table

I am looking to add multiple `tbody` to my `asp.net table`. 
This is what I have tried so far

```
TableRow tbody = new TableRow();
tbody.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
row.Attributes.Add("data-filter", "featured");
cell.Text = "Featured";
row.Cells.Add(cell);
tbody.Controls.Add(row);//throws an error saying tablerow can't have table row as child
Table1.Rows.Add(tbody);
```

This throws an error that i can't have table row as child of table row, which sounds legit. But I wan't the row to be under the `<tbody>` and can't seem to figure out how to go about it. My desired output is

```
<tbody>
      <tr data-filter="featured">
         <td>Featured</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015839/how-to-create-thead-and-tbody-in-asp-net-table

Comment: No, that doesn't help at all. I can't create tbody dynamically. yea, I may place the row inside tbody by using `TableRowSection.TableBody` but i want multiple tbodies and be able to place differnt rows into different tbody

Comment: Why do you want multiple `tbody` tags inside of a single `table`? Or am I misunderstanding your multiple tbodies statement?

Comment: @karl well, I want it for reasons hard to explain. And no you are not misunderstanding. I wan't multiple tbodies inside of a single table. It is html complaint to have multiple tbodies inside of a single table, its not wrong. My question is how to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple `<tbody>` elements aren't possible with `<asp:Table>`, the `TableSection` property defines the 'section' that the row should be rendered in, however the control itself only renders one element per `TableRowSection`

As for the exception, you don't need the nested `TableRow` object, try this:

```
TableRow tbody = new TableRow();
tbody.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
tbody.Attributes.Add("data-filter", "featured");
cell.Text = "Featured";
tbody.Cells.Add(cell);
Table1.Rows.Add(tbody);
```

Here is the output:

```
<table id="MainContent_Table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-filter="featured">
        <td>Featured</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To achieve what you are after, you could try creating a custom control, or possibly the simplest solution, would be to use `HtmlGenericControl` and build the table elements that way, not the most elegant but it has the desired result:

```
var table = new HtmlGenericControl("table");
var tbody = new HtmlGenericControl("tbody");
var tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
var td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");

tr.Attributes.Add("data-filter", "featured");
td.InnerText = "Featured";
tr.Controls.Add(td);

tbody.Controls.Add(tr);
table.Controls.Add(tbody);

tbody = new HtmlGenericControl("tbody");
tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
tr.Attributes.Add("data-filter", "featured");
td.InnerText = "Featured";
tr.Controls.Add(td);

tbody.Controls.Add(tr);
table.Controls.Add(tbody);

Page.Controls.Add(table);
```

Here is the output:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-filter="featured">
            <td>Featured</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-filter="featured">
            <td>Featured</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thats true, but how to create a second `tbody` and add rows to it which is my actual question (`multiple tbodies`)

Comment: Sorry you're right, I didn't cover the actual question, I have updated my answer to include more details, hopefully it will suffice.

Comment: Awesome, using `HtmlGenericControl` totally escaped my head. Better yet, I think i can use html table with `runat=server` attribute.