# Add <thead> tags to Table using System.Web.UI.WebControls

Tags: c#

I need to add `<thead>` tags to my loop somehow. The tableHEaderRow class only uses `<tr><th>` tags, and I need them nested in a `<thead>` tag for styling purposes.

I have tried using a variety of methods including string writer, and literal controls but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
tbl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<thead>")); // This is the line I need to add
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
  TableHeaderCell th = new TableHeaderCell();
  th.Text = col.Caption;
  thr.Controls.Add(th);
}
tbl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</thead>")); // This is the line I need to add
tbl.Controls.Add(thr);
...
...
tbl.RenderControl(w);
tableString = sw.ToString();

// Then my aspx page displays my tableString variable.
```

What other ways Can I try to add the `<thead>` tags into my loop manually?
I am using System.Web.UI.WebControls.

Comment: When I try to use literalControl I get `Table' cannot have children of type 'LiteralControl`

Comment: It has been asked many times, even here on SO (start looking into [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thead+asp.net))

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create thead and tbody in ASP.NET Table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015839/how-to-create-thead-and-tbody-in-asp-net-table)

Comment: I have yet to see an answer @AndreasNiedermair that is c# code. I'm not looking for aspx code.

Comment: @Frantumn is there something you can't do in C#? That's way to do it and it's the answer even if...it's not ready to use code.

Comment: @Frantumn really?! ... `new TableHeaderRow()`... are you trolling?

Answer (score 3):

You set a TableRow control as being in a `<thead>` with the [TableSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.tablesection(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

For example: `<asp:TableRow TableSection="TableHeader"/>` will generate a TableRow control in the `<thead>` section of the table.

Dynamically, you can also set `rowControl.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;`

The three options are TableHeader, TableBody and TableFooter.